# ZendSearch in Symfony: "Index is under processing now"

Tags: php, symfony, lucene, zend-search-lucene

Any ideas?

`Uncaught PHP Exception ZendSearch\Lucene\Exception\RuntimeException: "Index is under processing now" at some/path/vendor/zendsearch/library/ZendSearch/Lucene/Index.php line 154.`

This is in `prod` mode of *Symfony*. This caused **500** error in my *admin* pages.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have the same problem now. Seems that the process hung up or something. But I don't know why and how i can kill it...

Comment: I actually made this working. I'm gonna answer myself later.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this. I'll try to explain what happened in my case.

In my scenario, one of the reasons *“Index is under processing now”* occurs is not because it's literally *waiting* for something. `segments.gen` is actually not mapped correctly.

There are two repositories. One is my development repository (**repo A**), I made a lot of changes in this repo A. Adding, editting a lot of files made the `segments.gen` to be updated. `segments.gen` adds and edits files too for its mapping for *indexing* (searching) purposes. Now, I merged a big folder to the other repository (**repo B**). This caused the `segments.gen` in the repo B to be out of sync.

What I did to solve this is issue is, I replaced the folder where the `segments.gen` is located along with the other files (including the ones generated by `segments.gen`) of repo B from repo A. Then, it works!

Comment: Did you replace multiple of the files?
I have many of the segments.gen files

./app/data/sulu_account/segments.gen
./app/data/sulu_snippet-de-i18n/segments.gen
./app/data/sulu_page_durchblick_digital-de_de-i18n/segments.gen
./app/data/sulu_contact/segments.gen
./app/data/sulu_media-de-i18n/segments.gen
./app/data/sulu_page_durchblick_digital-de-i18n/segments.gen

Comment: Okay, i synced the whole app/data folder and now it works. Thanks a lot.